# setAttribute not working with onClick in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, create-react-app, setattribute

A variable ("navBtn") set to document.createElement("span") creates a span but using setAttribute on that span is not working for some reason. The navBtn variable is in its own function and the setAttribute is trying to use an onClick to call a different function.I'm following along with a video using regular Javascript to make a carousel/slideshow. I'm not sure how much the code should change from regular JavaScript to React so I've tried binding the method, using JSX, regular JavaScript, etc. But nothing seems to be working.

I'm trying to recreate the carousel from this website: https://www.spacex.com/
I didn't know how to make one so I started following along with a video that had the same functionalities of the slideshow from the website but tweaked it in my own way to look like the one from SpaceX. This is in Create-react-app and the video I'm following is in plain JavaScript which is why I'm not using props or states YET.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import './Showcase.css';

var slideIndex, slides, navBtns, captionText;
class Showcase extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.moveSlide = this.moveSlide.bind(this);
        this.plusSlides = this.plusSlides.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.initGallery();
    }
    initGallery(){
        slideIndex = 0;
        slides = document.getElementsByClassName('imageHolder');
        slides[slideIndex].style.opacity = 1;

        captionText = document.querySelector('.captionHolder .captionText');
        captionText.innerText = slides[slideIndex].querySelector(".captionText").innerText;

        navBtns=[];
        var navBtnsContainer = document.getElementById('navBtnsContainer');

        for(var i=0; i < slides.length; i++){
            var navBtn = document.createElement("span");
            navBtn.classList.add("navBtns");
            navBtn.setAttribute("onClick", "{() => this.moveSlide("+i+")}");
            navBtnsContainer.append(navBtn);
            navBtns.push(navBtn);
        };

        navBtns[slideIndex].classList.add("active");
    }
    plusSlides(n){
        this.moveSlide(slideIndex + n);
    }
    moveSlide(n){
        var i, current, next;
        var moveSlideAnimClass = {
            forCurrent: "",
            forNext: ""
        };
        if(n > slideIndex){
            if(n>=slides.length){n=0}
            moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent = "moveLeftCurrentSlide";
            moveSlideAnimClass.forNext = "moveLeftNextSlide";
        } else if(n < slideIndex){
            if(n < 0){n = slides.length - 1}
            moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent = "moveRightCurrentSlide";
            moveSlideAnimClass.forNext = "moveRightNextSlide";
        }
        if(n != slideIndex){
            next = slides[n];
            current = slides[slideIndex];
            for(i=0; i<slides.length;i++){
                slides[i].className="imageHolder";
                slides[i].style.opacity=0;
                navBtns[i].classList.remove("active");
            }
            current.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent);
            next.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forNext);
            navBtns[n].classList.add("active");
            slideIndex=n;
            slides[slideIndex].style.opacity = 1;
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <section id="Showcase"> {/*CONTAINS ALL SLIDING IMAGES*/}
                <div className="captionHolder">
                    {/* <p className="captionText"></p> */}
                    <Link exact to="/amos" className="captionText"></Link>
                    <Link exact to="/amos">Watch Replay</Link>
                    <div id="right" onClick={() => this.plusSlides(1)}>RIGHT</div>
                    <div id="left" onClick={() => this.plusSlides(-1)}>LEFT</div>
                </div>
                <div className="imageHolder"> {/*HOLDS ALL IMAGES HERE*/}
                    <img src="https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/amos17_v2.jpg" alt="Amos-17 Mission"/>
                    <p className="captionText">Amos-17 Mission</p>
                </div>

                <div className="imageHolder"> {/*HOLDS ALL IMAGES HERE*/}
                    <img src="https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/v2_smallsatheader.png" alt="RideShare Missions"/>
                    <p className="captionText">Smallsat Rideshare Program</p>
                </div>

                <div className="imageHolder"> {/*HOLDS ALL IMAGES HERE*/}
                    <img src="https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/nasa_astronauts3.jpg" alt="NASA Astronauts on crew Dragon"/>
                    <p className="captionText">NASA Astronauts on Crew Dragon</p>
                </div>

                <div id="navBtnsContainer"></div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Showcase;
```

If I try writing the code the 'React' way, onClick={() => this.moveSlide(i)}
I get no error but no result either. I've gotten other errors when trying to write this setAttribute in different ways that you normally wouldn't for a React onClick attribute. The result should be that clicking the created span should move the slideshow to the next image and set the next navBtn with the "active" class. The way I would like it to look is here https://www.spacex.com/

Answer (score 2):

try

```
  navBtn.setAttribute("onClick", "this.moveSlide("+i+")");
```

or

```
  navBtn.setAttribute("onClick", "{this.moveSlide("+i+")}");
```

Comment: Tried both before and they both still give this error, (index):37 Uncaught TypeError: this.moveSlide is not a function
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):37)

Comment: So with those two attempts, the onClick must've been responsive successfully but still getting an error from it.Before it was just not responsive at all with no error and no result. Regular onClicks work when I put them as an attribute on actual elements but I can't do that for this span element since its a variable.

Comment: Any other ideas? Been stuck on this for one full night :(

Comment: No worries, I got it working with an addEventListener. Thanks for your effort!